What should I do when a question in SG needs migrating?
Should I:

Approve + flag to ask for migrating?
Vote as off-topic + guide OP to the suitable site?


Migration means it does not belong here. Publishing means it belongs here. So, at the very least 1. is sending mixed signals. Also, you have to be absolutely positively sure that the question as-is would be a good fit on the target site you want to migrate it to. That means it's on-topic and it's high-quality. Unless you're an active member there, that's hard to ensure. We don't want to migrate questions that are only going to be closed. So, unless you're sure the question merits migration, it's usually a good practice to point the user to the target and their Help Center.

Probably you won't even be able to flag for migration, since migrations have caused so many problems in the past the number of options available are severely limited. Re-asking (and in the process rewording) is strongly preferred, with or without staging ground.

The Staging Ground doesn't have any tooling for migration. While this has been discussed during the beta, this was marked as status-deferred.
When you see a question that shouldn't be asked on Stack Overflow, the best option is probably to write a comment saying the question doesn't fit on Stack Overflow and that they can ask their question on the site it would be on-topic at. After than, you can vote to close it as off-topic (e.g. Not about programming or software development).
The author can then ask their question on the other site and it won't get published on Stack Overflow (assuming another reviewer agrees with your close vote).

I would suggest a little bit more cautious tone when suggesting other sites. Rather than saying "they can ask their question on site X", I suggest "they might be able to ask their question on site X". I have seen too many cases where a SO participant leaves a comment indicating the question should be asked on site X, but then it turns out that the question is not a good fit for site X (perhaps the SO regular was not familiar with the expectations on site X), and then the asker feels like they are getting "the run-around" and receiving conflicting information, which is frustrating for them.
